# How to find out number of pattern matches in a string or array in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

[log screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1vHq.jpg) I am trying below code to match number of occurances in a string or array, but failing to do so.

```
${result}=   cli    ${device}    timeout -t ${timeout} tcpdump -i v${vlan_id} -vv     prompt=\\#    timeout=${timeout1}    timeout_exception=0
@{result}=   Split String      ${result}    ,
:FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{result}
\     log   ***** ${ELEMENT} *****
log   ***** ${pattern} *****
${total}=    Count Values In List    ${result}    ${pattern}
Should Be True      ${total}  > ${count}
```

I am able to see the pattern when I am loggin it as "log   ***** ${ELEMENT} *****"
But same is not getting accounted for in below line

```
${total}=    Count Values In List    ${result}    ${pattern}
```

Please help with what I am doing wrong. I am attaching screen shot.

Thanks

Comment: could you please update your example to hard-code some data in `${result}`, since we can't call the `cli` keyword. Ideally this would be a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run in order to duplicate your results.

Comment: attached screen shot, which has data for ${result}

Comment: the screenshot doesn't help. If you need help, you need to be willing to put in a little effort. Give us a little test case that we can run so that we can see what you're seeing. It shouldn't take you more than just a few minutes to create.

Comment: I found out the issue, on splitting the string, there was a space before variable, because of which it was not counting, thank you for the help

Answer (score 2):

```
${result}=   cli    ${device}    timeout -t ${timeout} tcpdump -i v${vlan_id} -vv     prompt=\\#    timeout=${timeout1}    timeout_exception=0
```

Verify value of `${result}`, if it is giving desired output then in following code

```
@{result}=   Split String      ${result}    ,
```

instead of `@{result}` use another variable name Ex `@{resultKeyValue}`

Then use same variable and see output

```
${total}=    Count Values In List    ${resultKeyValue}    ${pattern}
```

Comment: I found out the issue, on splitting the string, there was a space before variable, because of which it was not counting, thank you for the help